# Element having same xpath

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 date calenders in the application and all calenders are having same id, xpath, name and css. I have used the option `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='imgIRBDate'][2]")).click();` to click on the second element. But it is showing Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException. How to select the second element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose complete xpath in brackets. Try following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='imgIRBDate'])[2]")).click();
```